# js while(true){} blocks event loop

Tags: javascript, event-loop

```
setInterval(function(){console.log("hello")},2000);
while(true){}
```

"hello" never gets printed.

I think event loop runs in a different thread, but here it seems like 'while loop' is preventing the 'event loop' from execution.
**Can somebody put some light on this?**

Comment: JS is single threaded.

Comment: I realise that I'm a hobbyist, but I've been using and writing JavaScript for a while now, and I've never yet seen a reason to use `while (true)`, `while (variableName) { if (something) { variableName = false; }` has its uses, but not an inevitably-infinite loop, so far as I can tell...

Comment: @DavidThomas `while(true)` definitely has its use: when you don't have a condition variable explicitly and when you need to repeat until something happens/completes/etc. A trivial example: https://pastebin.com/qEeuUxAs

Comment: Before passing 2000ms, the infinite loop take the control, as Chris G mentioned JS is single thread so there is no way to run another code, unless you remove the `while(true)`

Comment: @zerkms For those cases, `do … while` is often a better solution (or outright recursion). I only use `while (true)` when I have multiple break conditions at different points in the loop.

Comment: @Bergi `do..while` with what condition? How would you rewrite my example?

Comment: @zerkms probably `var result; do { try { result = await …; } catch(e) { result = null; } } while(!result)`. Or `await (function recurse() { return ….catch(recurse); }());`.

Comment: @Bergi I know it's a personal preference, but I find both of those ugly. (especially that you need to declare an additional variable simply to have a flag)

Comment: @zerkms it's not a flag, my promises usually return a meaningful result :-) Right, as a boolean it would be ugly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to understand

**How browser internally does setTimeout?**

I will explain in brief.

> **To learn  more about this**
>
> Here is more [detail explanation](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ) of event  loop by Philip Roberts
>   in [jsconf2014](https://2014.jsconf.eu/speakers/philip-roberts-what-the-heck-is-the-event-loop-anyway.html)
>
> [Philip Roberts: What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ)
>
> Also, to see this process in action there is a great tool take a look
>   at [loupe](http://latentflip.com/loupe)

To understand that you have to know about event queue in javascript. There are event queues implemented in browser. Whenever an event get triggered  in js, all of these events (like click etc.. ) are added to this queue.  When your browser has nothing to execute it takes an event from queue and executes them one by one.

Now,  when you call `setTimeout` or `setInterval` your callback get registered to an timer in browser and it gets added to the event queue after the given time expires and eventually javascript takes the event from the queue and executes it.

This happens so,  because javascript execution is **single threaded** and they can execute only one thing at a time. So,  they cannot execute other javascript and keep track of your timer. That is why these timers are registered with browser (browser are not single threaded) and it can keep track of timer and add an event in the queue after the timer expires.

same happens for `setInterval` only in this case the event is added to the queue again and again after the specified interval until it gets cleared or browser page refreshed.

> **Note**
>
> The delay parameter you pass to these functions is the minimum delay
>   time to execute the callback. This is because after the timer expires
>   the browser adds the event to the queue to be executed  by the
>   javascript engine but the execution of the callback depends upon your
>   events position in the queue and as the engine is single threaded it
>   will execute all the events in the queue one by one.

Hence, your callback may sometime take more than the specified delay time to be called specially when your other code blocks the thread and not giving it time to process what's there in the queue.

And as I mentioned javascript is single thread. So,  if you block the thread for long.

Like this code

```
while(true) { //infinite loop 
}
```

Your user may get a message saying **page not responding**.

And here, your `setTimeout` event will never execute.

Comment: "There is a event queue" --- there are actually multiple task queues. So depending on the task it is added to the corresponding queue.

Comment: Yes,  there are but I am not going on detail just giving an idea

Comment: "not going in detail" :D

Comment: "javascript engine are single threaded" --- that's not entirely correct either. Engines are surely multi-threaded. It's a JS userland that is single threaded.

Comment: By engine  I meant execution of javascript by js engine

Comment: Well, it's not me who you need to explain it, but to the less experienced OP (and other people who will read it in the future). When you explain things that are sensitive to details, I think it's the best to be as accurate as possible (just my 2c).

Comment: @zerkms thanks for the feedback will edit my answer to add details.

Comment: well that was surely a justifiable misunderstanding on my part.
i thought that as events are registered with browser and it's the browser which adds them to queue, so the execution of callbacks is also done by browser in a separate thread.

Comment: No,  it's not done by browser in separate thread.  The callback is executed in the js thread only. Browser will only add it to the event queue and javascript thread will pick it up from the queue and execute it.

Comment: For more indepth information I recommend to go through the resources I added thanks. :) I hope the answer  was helpful.

Comment: and hey guys i found this
** while (queue.waitForMessage()) {
  queue.processNextMessage();
}**
on mozilla js documentation pages.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

now if there is such a while loop waiting for events, how would you still say that js is single threaded?

Comment: What are you looking at `while(queue.waitForMessage())...` it is the internal implematation of event loop by browser that's not javascript and browser is not single threaded.

Answer (score 5):

Non-blocking while loop:

```
let done = false;

setTimeout(() => {
  done = true
}, 5);

const eventLoopQueue = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    setImmediate(() => {
      console.log('event loop');
      resolve();
    })
  );
}

const run = async () => {
  while (!done) {
    console.log('loop');
    await eventLoopQueue();
  }
}

run().then(() => console.log('Done'));
```