# Why is this loop endless?

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop

Why variable `a` with value 2 does not pass into the cycle after 2 seconds?

```
let a = 1;
setVar()
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function setVar(){
    await sleep(2000);
    a = 2;
}

while(a === 1)
{}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Because the function is asynchronous.

Comment: You have a single thread. Code only checks for async callbacks after the thread has processed all the synchronous code. That never happens because the while loop never ends, so you never get a chance to get the async callbacks.

Comment: @Spectric I know it. Please explain to me more.

Comment: It's a bit tricky, but can you try to call setVar() after defiling the functions it's using? Also you can add a promise style `.catch()` call to the `setVar()` call: `setVar().catch(console.error.bind(console));`, as I'm also suspecting a Undefined error being swallowed somewhere. also your code is using a single thread, which probably is being occupied by the while loop and it's preventing the thread to even resolve the callbacks.

Comment: @SaleemKhair I did it but no changes.

Comment: Call `setVar()` within the while loop, I'm not sure what's the purpose of the func but I believe that will unblock the while.

Answer (score 1):

Hi answer for your question is in this post:

[js while(true){} blocks event loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343232/js-whiletrue-blocks-event-loop)

Your event loop is blocked by your `while` loop so asynchrounous actions like your Promise in `setVar` cannot resolve